# I cannot get the UIScrollView to adjust its size based on UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

There are so many discussions on the subject between WebView in ScrollView or ScrollView in WebView that I'm completely lost!

In my case, I have a ScrollView which owns a UIImageView of a fixed size and a UIWebView of a variable size.

I used the following solution which seems to correctly compute the height, according to NSLog() output:

*** Edit ***
My web view is initialised  as follow:

```
    CABBndGMedia *htmlMedia = [[currentPOI listMediaHtml] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[htmlMedia localMediaFilename]];
    poiHtml.delegate = self;
    [poiHtml loadData:htmlData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
    poiHtml.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

And then:

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{

    CGRect frame = poiHtml.frame;
    frame.size.height = 1;
    poiHtml.frame = frame;
    CGSize fittingSize = [poiHtml sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    frame.size = fittingSize;
    poiHtml.frame = frame;

    NSLog(@"size: %f, %f", fittingSize.width, fittingSize.height);

}
```

*** Edit ***
After changing the Scrollview background colour, I realised that the WebView doesn't change its height, despite the fittingSize.height value display.

This problem seems to be very "weather" depend according to everything I read in Stackoverflow where some solutions seem to work for someone, not for the other....
Anyway, what could I miss to get this solution, which seem to be the best one, working?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The `UIScrollView`s frame should be the boundaries within which you wish the content to be clipped.  So probably the size of your screen.

You need to set the `contentSize` property of the scroll view to be the full size that you have calculated.  Then the scroll view will allow you to scroll within that size.

Comment: Hi jeffamaphone, I edited my post to add more infos after more tests. In fact, the WebView's height is not updated.